# Android Studio Beginner here

Tags: kotlin

I am taking the coursera course for mobile application development and I am doing my first project, my build launches successfully then immediately crashes. I am not sure why it is doing this so any insight into the matter would be greatly appreciated. Below is my build...

```
package com.example.video_player

import android.R
import android.net.Uri
import android.net.Uri.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val videoView = findViewById(R.id.testView)
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        val uri:Uri = parse(
            "android.resource://" + packageName
                    + "/raw/test"
        )
        
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.video_player.MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/testView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="308dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


This is my first build and i am following a tutorial and am just getting error after error, when i get the errors to clear the app crashes directly after launch.
```

Comment: Please include your log in order to understand what kinda error you get.
Anyway at a first glance it may have something to to with the uri, try this
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context?.packageName + "/" + R.raw.test)

Comment: Specifically, open the *Logcat* tab and make sure your running app is selected, and the filter is set to *show only selected application*. If it's a reproducible crash it's sometimes quicker to just open Logcat, and run the app and get the crash, it gets it displayed quicker. Then you'll see a stacktrace for the crash, marked as *Error* level logging (usually red). That'll tell you the exception that caused the crash (often with some very helpful info), and below that will be what caused it, and what caused *that*, etc, with line numbers. Always post that info here, but you might solve it too!

Comment: i cannot figure out how to post my log as it says i have to much code in my post, how do i get around this so i can share my logcat info?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setMediaController(android.widget.MediaController)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                     at com.example.videoplayer4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)